# Importing modules across different folders

Tags: import, module, package, init

I have the following structure:

```
/Control
    __init__.py
    main.py
    /MyFunctions
        __init__.py
        test.py
    /Scripts
        __init__.py
        undefined.py
```

From the `undefined.py` script, I want to import some functions written inside the `test.py` file. Therefore I've tried several important statements, for example `from MyFunctions.test import sortedList`. I also tried `from Control.MyFunctions.test import sortedList`. In both cases I get a 'ModuleNotFoundError'...

I don't know why this is not working... Could someone help me please?

Thank you.